# How to use clang -cc1 to link object files

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

In clang, I can just use `clang file.o -o file.exe` and it links the object file to a executable.

But there's a reason I must link **file.o** using just `-cc1` and that's because I have embedded it in a C++ application. How can I link it using C++?

When you give a **.o** file to clang with `-cc1` option, clang thinks its a source file and produces errors for it.

Comment: Why are you trying to invoke the compiler front end to link an executable?

Comment: embedding the main driver file would indeed be great, but the main function in the driver file takes a reference to ToolContext which provides the path to the clang binary, however zig programming language also uses the cc1 file and not the main driver file

I could embed it my c++ language, BUT that scares me that if clang is not installed on user's machine, It might fail

Comment: zig c++ implementation embeds clang using cc1

Comment: But does it use cc1 for linking? As far as i can see from a quick Google the driver does the linking, cc1 is only a compiler

Comment: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/56d45b09dcd6c880215481bcc3c6d6281a04d264/clang/tools/driver/driver.cpp#L228

Comment: clang can be used for linking, clang does link object files and create a .exe, also links with standard lib by default

Comment: `clang` is the **C** toolchain driver.  `clang++` is the **C++** toolchain driver.

Comment: Yes, but the file you've linked to is the driver, not  the cc1 compiler

Comment: The problem is that when I try to link using lld I must provide -lc flag to link with the standard library, I tried to that, it works on windows and on linux it fails because it can't find the standard library so it cays, can't find library -lc

Comment: handling this job to clang is better since it will do the job of searching and finding the path of standard library and then link it, but the main function takes a path argument, which is again risky, I am developing a single binary compiler that must compile my language and generate a executable without depending on anything else (other installations)

Comment: @AlanBirtles so you are saying once my compiler has been built into an exe, It still would require clang

Comment: how do other programming languages handle this...?

Comment: "But there's a reason I must link file.o using just -cc1" There is a reason I must draw a triangle with sides 3, 4 and 17 on the Euclidean plane. What are my next steps?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI What do you think I should do if I want to generate an executable out of llvm::Module without depending on any external binary like other programming languages

Comment: "it fails because it can't find the standard library " So that's your real problem.

Comment: just not being able to find the standard library is not my problem, I'm embedding clang so user would invoke my application, so clang would find the standard library, my usage of clang is not my concern, I could link with any standard lib, but I don't want user to go through the same thing @n.m.couldbeanAI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't do that. `clang -cc1...`  invokes the *compiler only*. It does not do linking. If you input an object file it treats it as a source file because the
compiler can only consume source files and output object files.

Look at this - verbose output of compiling and linking a simple program with clang:

```
$ clang -v -o prog main.cpp
Ubuntu clang version 16.0.6 (15)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/lib/llvm-16/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/home/imk/develop/so/scrap1 -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-16/lib/clang/16 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/13 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/backward -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-16/lib/clang/16/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/home/imk/develop/so/scrap1 -ferror-limit 19 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /tmp/main-e80981.o -x c++ main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 16.0.6 based upon LLVM 16.0.6 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/13
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/backward
 /usr/lib/llvm-16/lib/clang/16/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -pie -z relro --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o prog /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/main-e80981.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/crtendS.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

You see that:

```
"/usr/lib/llvm-16/bin/clang" -cc1 ... -o /tmp/main-e80981.o -x c++ main.cpp
```

compiles `main.cpp`, as C++, to the object file `/tmp/main-e80981.o`. Then *the linker* does the linking:

```
"/usr/bin/ld" ... -o prog ... /tmp/main-e80981.o ...
```

Perhaps it helps that [the clang source file you pointed to](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/56d45b09dcd6c880215481bcc3c6d6281a04d264/clang/tools/driver/driver.cpp#L228)
appears to be the main source file for the frontend `clang` command, not `clang -cc1`, and that the main source file for the *compiler* appears to be [this one](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/56d45b09dcd6c880215481bcc3c6d6281a04d264/clang/tools/driver/cc1_main.cpp). If that is right - and I have only taken a
quick glance at the source - then you might hope to proceed to by embedding a call to `clang`, not `clang -cc1`.